# Are 3d assets purchased from assets website, say turbosquid editable?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I want to save my time in modelling and sculpturing 3d model. I found some assets in turbosquid close to what I want. If I buy it, can it be edited in all aspect? How to know a 3d model in turosquid is editable? If there is no editable 3d model in turbosquid, any other sources to find editable 3d assets?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Answer (score 6):

Yes they are,

Re [TURBOSQUID](https://www.turbosquid.com/)

> **[Do I have the right to modify Stock Media Products?](https://blog.turbosquid.com/royalty-free-license/#modify-products)**
>
> Yes. You may modify them to make your Creations. Please keep in mind
>   that no matter how much you modify a Stock Media Product, it still may
>   only be distributed as a Creation and is subject to the rules of the
>   Royalty Free License.

please read the [TURBO SQUID licensing terms](https://support.turbosquid.com/hc/en-us/sections/206607507-Licensing-Usage) to be sure you can use them for your intended purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, most types of 3d files is editable in blender no matter what. Modelling to shading and textures and more.But only some types,
Collada, Motion capture, Alembic, Scalable vector graphics, Stanford, Stl, Fbx, glTF 2.0, Wavefront and X3d Extensible 3d

if they are in other types (eg-.max, .usd) you have convert them in to one of above with different 3d software to import it.